# Keeping size uniform in standalone pages while using tikz-3dplot

Tags: standalone, tikz-3dplot

The change of the viewpoint's angles in `tikz-3dplot` changes the different pages while using `standalone`. How could I keep that size uniform?

Adding a rectangle as background didn't work either, so a more reasonable solution is to add some rotation invariant object. A sphere with opacity zero so that from both angles (from any) should leave the size invariant. But I didn't succeed to draw such sphere (a ball command is not for 3d, is it?).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{50}
\begin{tikzpicture}     [tdplot_main_coords]

\draw[-latex]  (-1,-1,-1) --  (1,1,1);

\end{tikzpicture}

% now arrow seen from other angle, but the page shrinks
\tdplotsetmaincoords{30}{90}
\begin{tikzpicture}     [tdplot_main_coords]

\draw[-latex]  (-1,-1,-1) --  (1,1,1);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why standalone?, any other class would have constant page size

Comment: I needed separate pages, that's the first environment that I knew to satisfy this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could center the tikzpicture in a minipage.

```
\documentclass[multi={minipage},border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[c][3.47cm][c]{3.47cm}% sqrt(12)
\centering
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{50}
\begin{tikzpicture}     [tdplot_main_coords]

\draw[-latex]  (-1,-1,-1) --  (1,1,1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[c][3.47cm][c]{3.47cm}
\centering
% now arrow seen from other angle, but the page shrinks
\tdplotsetmaincoords{30}{90}
\begin{tikzpicture}     [tdplot_main_coords]

\draw[-latex]  (-1,-1,-1) --  (1,1,1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```